# remove image file from backend with node File System and MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, fs

I need to remove an image file from my backend, the folder is: /uploads. When i call the function deleteProduct it removes the product from the data base but the image of the product its still in folder.

```js
deleteProduct: (req, res) => {
        let productId = req.params.id;
        Product.findById(productId, (err, res) =>{
            var imageResponse = res.image; 
            console.log(imageResponse); 
        });
        //console.log(imageResponse);
        //fs.unlink('./uploads' + imageResponse );
```

When i try to access imageResponse outside the findById, console prints: "imageResponse" is not defined. Then i need to delete that file with fs. Im not sure if i wrote correct the unlink function. Thanks in advance.

Comment: res.image should be a url .  take the url , convert to a path in the fs . get an instance of 'file' from the fs path and when u have a ref to the file , call delete on it

Comment: when i log imageResponse i get the name of the image of the product, then i need to pass that name to the File System unlink function but i dont know how, i can't access imageResponse outside the findById function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**For fs.unlink**

Have you made sure to:

1. Include `fs = require('fs')`?
2. Used __dirname?
3. Include file extension (.png, .jpg, .jpeg)?

```
const fs = require('fs');

fs.unlink(__dirname + '/uploads' + imageResponse + ".png", (err) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('successfully deleted file');
});
```

**For image response being undefined**

You didn't provide information on the Product constructor, but I assume Product.findById is asynchronous. You may need to use an async function

```
const fs = require('fs');

async function deleteProduct (req, res) => {
        let productId = req.params.id;
        Product.findById(productId, (err, res) =>{
            var imageResponse = res.image; 
            console.log(imageResponse);
            fs.unlink(__dirname + '/uploads' + imageResponse + ".png", (err) => {
              if (err) throw err;
              console.log('successfully deleted file');
            });
        });
}
```

Further reading:
Node File API: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html
Async functions: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Answer (score 0):

Finally it seems to be working, the file succesfully vanished from the folder, im still open for advices, thanks.

```js
deleteProduct: (req, res) => {
        let productId = req.params.id;
        Product.findById(productId, (err, res) =>{
            if(err) return res.status(500).send({message: 'Error'});
            fs.unlink('./uploads/' + res.image, (err) => {
                if(err) return res.status(500).send({message: 'Error'});
            })
});
```

Comment: It appears you have copied code from my answer, if my answer helped you, could you please accept.